# BeautifulSoup4 not able to scrape data from table

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I want to scrape the column 2 and 3 of  table of site 
      https://www.airvistara.com/fly/flightschedule
the code i used is

```
import bs4 as bs
from urllib2 import urlopen

sauce=urlopen('https://www.airvistara.com/fly/flightschedule').read()
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')
table=soup.table
table_body=table.find('tbody')
table_rows=table_body.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td=tr.find_all('td')
    row=[i.text for i in td]
    print row
```

But i am not able to find the desired solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you're trying to parse is loaded via `ajax`, which is not available to `bs`.
Here's a working code to get the **Outbound Flights** on a python dictionary:

```
import json
import requests

post_fields = {"flightDate":"22/04/2017"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'https://www.airvistara.com/fly/getFlightschedule'
json_response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(post_fields), headers=headers).text
decoded_json = json.loads(json_response)
print decoded_json
```

---

Output:

```
{u'flightSchedule': [{u'effectiveFrom': u'19-APR-2017', u'flightCode': u'UK 0946', u'baseFareL1': 0, u'flightDate': u'Saturday, 28 October 2017',...
```

---

To get the details for each flight, you can use:

```
for flight in decoded_json['flightSchedule']:
    print flight['effectiveFrom']
    print flight['flightCode']
    print flight['baseFareL1']
    print flight['flightDate']
    print flight['daysOfOperation']
    print flight['arrivalStation']
    print flight['departureStation']
    print flight['via']
    print flight['scheduledArrivalTime']
    print flight['departureCityName']
    print flight['effectiveTo']
    print flight['arrivalCityName']
    print flight['scheduledDepartureTime']
```

Which will output something like:

```
19-APR-2017
UK 0946
0
Saturday, 28 October 2017
Daily
DEL
AMD
-
10:25
Ahmedabad
28-OCT-2017
New Delhi
08:45
```

---

Notes:
1 - If you need to specify the `arrivalStation` or `departureStation`, use:

```
post_fields = {"flightDate":"22/04/2017","arrivalStation":"AIRPORTCODE","departureStation":"AIRPORTCODE"}
```

Comment: It worked. can i show this data in front end using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Sure, you may want to pass the raw `json` to `javascript`, for example, via `php`. You may want to search on google or open a new question about this. If my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer.